# When using tilt, how do I stop docker containers but not delete them?

Tags: docker, tilt

I've begun using [tilt](https://tilt.dev/) for Docker development and love it! I have containers that take a long time to build though. When I'm done using them, I don't want to run `tilt down`  ([docs](https://docs.tilt.dev/cli/tilt_down.html)) because rebuilding them can take time. Also, running Ctrl-C doesn't stop the containers at all.

Is there a way to disable the containers without killing them in tilt?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop the containers without rebuilding them or killing them in Tilt, you can use the command **`tilt down --keep=containers`**. This will halt the Tilt process and keep the containers running, so you can resume your work without rebuilding them later. Just remember to use `tilt up` when you're ready to continue working with those containers.

Comment: Can you point the reference for the `--keep` flag? I couldn't find it and it didn't work on my tilt (`v0.33.6 [latest]`).